# Spritekit - Increase duration every 10 points

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I have this very simple game that I want to increase the spawn time when the user gets a score of 10. I need to keep increasing the delayBubbleSpawn_action every 1 second for every 10 points the user gets. How do I do this? I tried using the case statement but it is not working.

```
func movingEverything() {

    //Modify this to increase every 1 second for every 10 points
    let delayBubbleSpawn_action = SKAction.waitForDuration(delayBubbleSpawn)



    //Need to modify this block of code
    runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addCones),
        SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addBubbles),
            delayBubbleSpawn_action]))]))


    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(lifeBubble),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(10.0)])))        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this will do:

```
var delayBubbleSpawn = INITIAL_DELAY + points%10
```

It starts with a spawn time of `INITIAL_DELAY` and increments it by one every 10 `points`.